# Draw temporary circle in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, web-applications

I am trying to create a canvas, with a picture in it, where on click, a circle is created, to fade out over a certain time.

I am a total newbie to javascript, but this is what I have been able to cobble together so far: a canvas with the picture in it, and a function to draw a circle on click.

I would like to  have the circle fade out, and a function that lets the user delete the last circle. Any ideas on how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
<section class="mbr-section mbr-section-nopadding mbr-figure--caption-outside-bottom" id="image1-1">
    <div class="mbr-figure">
        <img id="mave" height="0" src="assets/images/mave2.png">

<canvas id="imgCanvas" width="730" height="410" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;" onclick="draw(event)"></canvas>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
var c = document.getElementById("imgCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("mave");
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("imgCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function draw(e) {
    var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    posx = pos.x;
    posy = pos.y;
    context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(posx, posy, 20, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    context.fill();
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
      y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once something is drawn on the Canvas it is essentially forgotten about and is just some pixels. So if you want to interact with the shapes you've drawn you need to store them.

You could have an array of circles which holds circle objects.

```
var Circle = function (x, y, radius) {
    this.x = x; //Centre of the circle
    this.y = y; //Centre of the circle
    this.radius = radius;
};

var circlesArray = [];
```

Then when you want to add a circle you can create a new circle object and add it to the array.

```
circlesArray.push(new Circle(x, y, radius));
```

Then to draw them create a function that loops through the array and draw each circle

```
function drawCircles() {
    for (var i = 0; i < circlesArray.length; i++) {
        var circle = circlesArray[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}
```

Then to delete the last circle that was drawn you could use `circlesArray.pop()` to remove the last circle.

Once the last circle has been removed you can clear the Canvas with `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);` and recall the `drawCircles()` function.

Here is a good example of a fade function from another question - [How to fade out an item in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141792/how-to-fade-out-an-item-in-canvas)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you'll need to store the circles somewhere. 
`var circles = [];`

Then you'll have to run a function every N milliseconds to make the circles fade.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("imgCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("mave");
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    setInterval(tick, 33);//this call
}
```

And a handler.

```
function tick(){
    draw();
}
```

Then modify the `draw` function.

```
function draw(e) {
    //clear the context
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //if we call it on click - create a new circle, add it to array
    if(e){
        var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
        circles.push({x : pos.x, y : pos.y, r : 20, alpha : 1});
    }
    //then fade out existing circles
    for(var i = circles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        circles[i].alpha -= 0.005;
        if(circles[i].alpha <= 0){//cleanup dead ones
            circles.splice(i, 1);
            continue;
        }
        context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, " + circles[i].alpha + ")";
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, circles[i].r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        context.fill();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In canvas after you draw, the pixels are on the canvas.

If you want the image still there and the circle will disappear, you need to keep draw the image.

```
setInterval(function(){
    draw();
},refreshRate);
```

When user click, save the position of the circle to a array.

draw image > draw circle (draw by the data of circle array)

after the circle fade out, remove the circle data that stored at the array and draw the image, then it the circle will not draw. If you want to remove last circle, just remove the last item of the list.

```
<canvas id="imgCanvas" width="730" height="410" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

<script>
//game config
var canvas=document.getElementById("imgCanvas");
var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
var ch = canvas.height;
var cw = canvas.width;

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var img = new Image();
img.src = "mave2.png";

var circleArray = new Array();

// functions
window.onload = function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        canvasContext.drawImage(img,0,0,cw,ch);
        drawArrayCircle();
    },500);

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (evt) {
        var mousePos = calculateMousePos(evt);
        handleClickButton(mousePos);
    });
};


function saveCircleData(pos){
    circleArray.push(pos);
    console.log(circleArray);
}

function fadeOutCircle(){

}

function drawArrayCircle(){
    for(i=0;i<circleArray.length;i++){
         console.log(circleArray[i]);
        if (circleArray[i] != null) {
            if (!circleArray[i].opacity) {
                circleArray[i].opacity=1;
            } 

            drawOneCircle(i);
        }
    }
}

function drawOneCircle(index) {

    posx = circleArray[index].x;
    posy = circleArray[index].y;
    canvasContext.fillStyle = "#000000";
    canvasContext.beginPath();
    canvasContext.globalAlpha = circleArray[index].opacity;
    circleArray[index].opacity= circleArray[index].opacity -0.1;
    if (circleArray[index].opacity < 0) {
        circleArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
    canvasContext.arc(posx, posy, 20, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    canvasContext.fill();
    canvasContext.globalAlpha = 1.0;
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
      y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

function handleClickButton(mousePos) {
    saveCircleData(mousePos);
}


function calculateMousePos(evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var root = document.documentElement;
    var mouseX = evt.clientX -rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
    var mouseY = evt.clientY -rect.top - root.scrollTop;
    return {
        x:mouseX,
        y:mouseY
    };
}

</script>
```